# Why does TypeScript can't match the parameter type in a class with the type defined in an interface

Tags: typescript

So I have this code:

```
interface R {
  run(p1: string): number;
}

class My implements R {
  run(p1) {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

For some reason, TS compiler can't figure out that `p1`'s type is string:

[image]

**Why?**

Interestingly, it does know that this method matches `run` method from an interface, because if I return string instead of a number like this:

```
class My implements R {
  run(p1) {
    return 's';
  }
}
```

It complains:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Class Heritage > Cautions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cautions) section in TS handbook that describes almost identical example:

> It’s important to understand that an implements clause is only a check that the class can be treated as the interface type. It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods at all. A common source of error is to assume that an implements clause will change the class type - it doesn’t!
>
> ```ts
> interface Checkable {
>   check(name: string): boolean;
> }
>
> class NameChecker implements Checkable {
>   check(s) {
>     // Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     // Notice no error here
>     return s.toLowercse() === "ok";                 
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, we perhaps expected that `s`’s type would be influenced by the `name: string` parameter of check. It is not - implements clauses don’t change how the class body is checked or its type inferred.

Comment: thanks, the idea was to define typings on an interface so that class stays clean of types (for better readability), yet have type checking in place :) do you know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: To be frank, I never thought how to tackle such a problem, so I am not aware of any neat solution. If you can use an object instead of a class the type checker will behave nicely, but this probably deviates too much from the original problem.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. Yeah, it does work correctly on an object